# Does Limecrete exist in North America?

Tags: concrete

I've been learning a little bit about [limecrete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_concrete#Limecrete)

And I thought it'd be fun to try a project with it (small one) but I can't seem to find it as a product in North America. Most (all?) references to 'limecrete' that I can find appear to be out of either Britain or in some cases, Australia.

Is it a product that is manufactured in the US at all? If so, does it go under a different common name? Is it something I could make myself using lime-based mortar perhaps?

Comment: Please follow this up with the results of your experiment. Poking around a little, you will need to be patient - they are talking about a week or more to get a floor hard enough to walk on. Lime-based mortar will not meet the definition, as that is a lime and portland cement product, and the "limecrete" folks are avoiding portland cement.

Answer (score 1):

I seriously doubt you'll find "limecrete" as a ready made product, but the lime you want (which you can then mix aggregate into) is "Mason's Lime" - unless you are abnormally brave and silly and want to risk playing with quicklime, which is VERY nasty stuff. Type S or SA (air-entraining - makes small bubbles which help various properties of the product) are probably what you want, and will be able to find at any well-stocked masonry supply.

From the second link below:

> Hydrated limes used in building applications are divided into four
>   types, as described in ASTM Standard Specification C 207 (Hydrated
>   Lime for Masonry Purposes): Type N – normal hydrated lime Type NA –
>   normal air-entraining hydrated lime Type S – special hydrated lime
>   Type SA – special air-entraining hydrated lime Types S and SA are
>   differentiated from Types N and NA principally by the unhydrated oxide
>   content and their water retention value. Type S must meet a water
>   retention value of 85%, while Type N hydrate lime must have a water
>   retention value of 75%. No distinction is made based on the nature and
>   source of limestone. The maximum air content of cement-lime mortar
>   made with Types NA and SA is 14%; with Types N or S lime, 7%.

[Type s and sa mason's lime described.](http://www.lime.org/documents/publications/free_downloads/fact-masonry.pdf)

[National Lime Association](http://www.lime.org/lime_basics/faq.asp)

[More about type S](http://anfacal.org/media/Biblioteca_Digital/Construccion/Mezclas_Repellados_y_Stuccos/AGC-TypeS_hydrated_lime_special.pdf)